# General question about oversampling with TSNE or PCA

Tags: python, r, pca, resampling

I have an unbalanced dataset and I am planning to use over-sampling (resampling) and finally, I want to use PCA or TSNE for a better demonstration of the data (the data has more than 50 dimensions). I am wondering if I can use PCA or TSNE with oversampling? if yes, should I do it after I run the resampling algorithm? what's the logical procedure to do it?

Comment: I second what MrFlick said about visiting cross validated instead. That said, I would take care to choose a sampling method that creates a dataset that adheres to the PCA/TSNE assumptions. For example, PCA assumes gaussian so your sampling method will need to produce a gaussian dataset -- versus TSNE which can be multimodal.

Comment: Frank Harrell’s tweet gives the statistician’s view on your approach: http://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473. (Don’t mess with the data. Use the right statistical methods (chiefly proper scoring rules).)